# Scala Stream tail laziness and synchronization

Tags: multithreading, scala, lazy-evaluation

In one of his videos (concerning Scala's lazy evaluation, namely `lazy` keyword), Martin Odersky shows the following implementation of `cons` operation used to construct a `Stream`:

```
def cons[T](hd: T, tl: => Stream[T]) = new Stream[T] {
  def head = hd
  lazy val tail = tl
  ...
}
```

So `tail` operation is written concisely using lazy evaluation feature of the language.

But in reality (in Scala 2.11.7), the implementation of `tail` is a bit less elegant:

```
@volatile private[this] var tlVal: Stream[A] = _
@volatile private[this] var tlGen = tl _
def tailDefined: Boolean = tlGen eq null
override def tail: Stream[A] = {
  if (!tailDefined)
    synchronized {
      if (!tailDefined) {
        tlVal = tlGen()
        tlGen = null
      }
    }

  tlVal
}
```

Double-checked locking and two volatile fields: that's roughly how you would implement a thread-safe lazy computation in Java.

**So the questions are**:

1. Doesn't `lazy` keyword of Scala provide any 'evaluated maximum once' guarantee in a multi-threaded case?
2. Is the pattern used in real `tail` implementation an idiomatic way to do a thread-safe lazy evaluation in Scala?

Comment: FWIW in the new collections which are being developed [the implementation](https://github.com/scala/collection-strawman/blob/master/collections/src/main/scala/strawman/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L382-L385) is far simpler.

Comment: @Jasper-M does this new implementation provide that 'evaluate maximum once' guarantee in multi-threaded case? If yes, how does it achieve that? Sorry for stupid questions, but I'm new to Scala and I don't see any principal differences of that code with what Martin initially showed on his slides.

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to ask the developers.

Comment: I also do not understand this new implementation, because as far as i can tell it will be evaluated every time method tail is accessed.

Comment: @L.Lampart If i'm not mistaken, the only thing that will be re-evaluated is the null check (as the field is volatile), which is pretty fast.

Comment: Are you talking about the new implementation? I don't see any volatile or null checking there

Comment: @L.Lampart The new implementation is a `lazy val`. They are guaranteed to be evaluated once on the first access.

Comment: Oh common, i did miss that. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doesn't lazy keyword of Scala provide any 'evaluated maximum once'
>   guarantee in a multi-threaded case?

Yes, it does, as others have stated.

> Is the pattern used in real tail implementation an idiomatic way to do
>   a thread-safe lazy evaluation in Scala?

### Edit:

I think I have the *actual* answer as to why not `lazy val`. `Stream` has public facing API methods such as `hasDefinitionSize` inherited from `TraversableOnce`. In order to know if a `Stream` has a finite size not, we need a way of checking *without materializing the underlying* `Stream` tail. Since `lazy val` doesn't actually expose the underlying bit, we can't do that.

This is backed by [SI-1220](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1220)

To strengthen this point, @Jasper-M points out that the new `LazyList` api in strawman (Scala 2.13 collection makeover) no longer has this issue, since the entire collection hierarchy has been reworked and there are no longer such concerns.

---

### Performance related concerns

I would say "it depends" on which angle you're looking at this problem. From a LOB point of view, I'd say definitely go with `lazy val` for conciseness and clarity of implementation. But, if you look at it from the point of view of a Scala collections library author, things start to look differently. Think of it this way, you're creating a library which will be potentially be used by many people and ran on many machines across the world. This means that you should be thinking of the memory overhead of each structure, especially if you're creating such an essential data structure yourself.

I say this because when you use `lazy val`, by design you generate an additional `Boolean` field which flags if the value has been initialized, and I am assuming this is what the library authors were aiming to avoid. The size of a `Boolean` on the JVM is of course VM dependent, by even a byte is something to consider, especially when people are generating large `Stream`s of data. Again, this is definitely *not* something I would usually consider and is definitely a micro optimization towards memory usage.

The reason I think performance is one of the key points here is [SI-7266](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3450) which fixes a memory leak in Stream. Note how it is of importance to track the byte code to make sure no extra values are retained inside the generated class.

The difference in the implementation is that the definition of `tail` being initialized or not is a method implementation which checks the generator:

```
def tailDefined: Boolean = tlGen eq null
```

Instead of a field on the class.

Answer (score 2):

Scala `lazy` values are evaluated only once in multi-threaded cases. This is because the evaluation of `lazy` members is actually wrapped in a synchronized block in the generated code.

Lets take a look at the simple claas,

```
class LazyTest {

  lazy val x = 5

}
```

Now, lets compile this with scalac,

```
scalac -Xprint:all LazyTest.scala
```

This will result in,

```
package <empty> {
  class LazyTest extends Object {
    final <synthetic> lazy private[this] var x: Int = _;
    @volatile private[this] var bitmap$0: Boolean = _;
    private def x$lzycompute(): Int = {
      LazyTest.this.synchronized(if (LazyTest.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
        {
          LazyTest.this.x = (5: Int);
          LazyTest.this.bitmap$0 = true
        });
      LazyTest.this.x
    };
    <stable> <accessor> lazy def x(): Int = if (LazyTest.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
      LazyTest.this.x$lzycompute()
    else
      LazyTest.this.x;
    def <init>(): LazyTest = {
      LazyTest.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to see... that the lazy evaluation is thread-safe. And you will also see some similarity to that "less elegant" implementation in Scala 2.11.7

You can also experiment with tests similar to following,

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class A(i: Int) {

  lazy val j = {
    println("calculating j")
    i + 1
  }

}

def checkLazyInMultiThread(): Unit = {

  val a = A(6)

  val futuresList = Range(1, 20).toList.map(i => Future{
    println(s"Future $i :: ${a.j}")
  })

  Future.sequence(futuresList).onComplete(_ => println("completed"))

}

checkLazyInMultiThread()
```

Now, the implementation in standard library avoids using `lazy` because they are able to provide a more efficient solution than this generic `lazy` translation.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are correct, `lazy val`s use locking precisely to guard against double evaluation when accessed at the same time by two threads. Future developments, furthermore, will give the same guarantees without locking.
2. What is idiomatic, in my humble opinion, is a highly debatable subject when it comes to a language that, by design, allows for a wide range of different idioms to be adopted. In general, however, application code tends to be considered idiomatic when going more into the direction of pure functional programming, as it gives a series of interesting advantages in terms of ease of testing and reasoning that would make sense to give up only in case of serious concerns. This concern can be one of performance, which is why the current implementation of the Scala Collection API, while exposing in most cases a functional interface, makes heavy use (internally and in restricted scopes) of `var`s, `while` loops and established patterns from imperative programming (as the one you highlighted in your question).